# Ubuntu doesn`t read the whole RAM

Tags: 16.04, thinkpad, android-studio

I have Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS and it only reads 3.6 GB of it. I tried to configure the graphics memory size in BIOS and made it the least value but it is not solved. Can anyone help me? Cause I'm doing a heavy process and I need my whole RAM.

Comment: And your whole RAM is? What's the output of?: free -h

Comment: Also 32-bit or 64-bit Ubuntu?

Comment: I noticed the same for me. I have 8 GB of RAM, and it only utilizes about 7.7 GB, but its not a big deal for me since i have plenty of RAM left.

Comment: Is this a 64-bit machine? If so, are you running the 64-bit version of Ubuntu? And the program you're running a 64-bit build? (Almost all the programs installed through Ubuntu's package manager on the 64-bit version of Ubuntu are 64-bit builds--aside from those written in interpreted languages that, similarly, can be run by 64-bit interpreters. But if a program is distributed as a binary through some other mechanism, that's sometimes 32-bit-only.) I recommend adding the output of `uname -m` to your question, the name of the ISO you used to install Ubuntu, and the model name of your machine.

Comment: @OctaVIve - You have discrete graphics for which some of the system memory is assigned plus some system reserved memory, as usual. Nothing to see there, everything is as it should be (most likely the same for the OP), move on...

Comment: see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/621255/why-does-the-system-report-7-7gb-of-total-ram-when-i-installed-8gb/621271#621271)

Comment: @CelticWarrior "move on..." love it!

Comment: i`m using 64 bit  , Thinkpad e550 , and this is the output of free- h

Comment: total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.6G        736M        1.7G        165M        1.2G        2.5G
Swap:          3.7G          0B        3.7G

Answer (score 2):

1. You most likely have only 3,90625GB of RAM, producers mark 4000MB as 4GB, but ubuntu iterprets it as 4000/1024 GB, which equals to mentioned value.
2. If you have integrated GPU then some RAM is reserved for it, also system reserves a bit. Let's say that sums up to about 306MB, that's it, now you have 3.6GB left.

Keep in mind that in spite of comments, 32 bit Linux OS also support huge amount of RAM due to using PAE.

Comment: 4GB of ram never ever means anything other than 4,294,967,297 bytes. Hard disk manufactures do tricks like mentioned, but ram must fully fill out the address space and are always a power of 2.